# Addin controller Shutdown

Tags: add-in, maf

I am using Addin framework for my project and i am using following code to shutdown addin.

AddInController ac = AddInController.GetAddInController(job);
 ac.shutdown();

This works fine and shutdown and unload the addin from the memory in normal scenario. If code written in Addin throws any exception then above can not be able to shutdown the addin.

What should i write to handle this scenario?

Thanks,
Denish

Comment: I just found that on the above scenario i got System.AppDomainUnloadedException exception.

Comment: If you load the add-in in a new AppDomain then an unhanlded exception on the add-ins AppDomain will bring the AppDomain down. Note that if the unhandled exception is thrown by a child process on the new AppDomain, it will crush the whole application.

Comment: Also check this MSDN blog entry by the System.AddIn team. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/05/01/using-appdomain-isolation-to-detect-add-in-failures-jesse-kaplan.aspx